# Pika + RabbitMQ + Tornado. Метод basic_publish асинхронный или нет?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, tornado

Здравствуйте. Может немного витиевато опишу вопрос и может не совсем корректно, но надеюсь знающим он будет понятен.

Учусь писать асинхронный код. В pika есть адаптер TornadoConnection, через него создаю асинхронный channel, создаю очередь, application tornado создан и запущен. Хочу теперь добавить в очередь сообщение используя метод `basic_publish`. в свою очередь `channel.basic_publish(...)` я вызываю внутри отдельно созданной карутины (функция с декоратором `@gen.coroutine`). Вопрос такой, basic_publish работает асинхронно или нет внутри карутины? или нужно писать вызов этой функции с yield: `yield channel.basic_publish(...)` что бы она работала асинхронно?

В коде посмотрел, вроде обычная функция и не сказать что она асинхронная. Спасибо.

Comment: Похоже, авторы библиотеки не ожидают, что `channel.basic_publish()` может заблокироваться на значимо длительное время.

Comment: Насколько я понял, что если код пишется асинхронно то весь код нужно делать асинхронно, и эту функцию в том числе